# What is the advantage of using .innerHTML for escaping characters?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to use escape characters in JS/HTML but I can't figure out how to do it. I've seen examples of `.innerHTML` being used but I don't understand how. Can someone please explain it in simple terms?

Comment: Question title doesn't match question body. Which one's correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add content as raw text (like, as the value of a text node), and then query the `.innerHTML` of the container, you get back escaped HTML because that's what it'd have to look like if you were to *set* the `.innerHTML`:

```
var d = document.createElement('span');
var t = document.createTextNode("<b>Hello World</b>");
d.appendChild(t);
console.log(d.innerHTML); // logs &lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b&gt;
```

It's just the way that the `.innerHTML` mechanism behaves.

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML), the only characters that are affected are `<`, `>`, and `&`.  There are times when it's useful to encode other characters with HTML entities. The most common situation I think is when you want to use quotes in an HTML attribute.

An alternative to using the browsers DOM behavior is to use your own JavaScript function. Here's a (slightly modified) version of the code use in the [doT template library](https://github.com/olado/doT):

```
    function encodeHTMLSource() {
      var encodeHTMLRules = { 
          "&": "&#38;", "<": "&#60;", ">": "&#62;", '"': '&#34;', "'": '&#39;', "/": '&#47;'
        },
        matchHTML = /&(?!#?\w+;)|<|>|"|'|\//g;

        return function() {
          return this ? this.replace(matchHTML, function(m) {
            return encodeHTMLRules[m] || m;
          }) : this;
        };
    }
    String.prototype.encodeHTML = encodeHTMLSource();
```

This function is designed to be added to the String prototype, which some might find distasteful (that seems to be a recent change; my older version doesn't do this).  The idea is that it uses a closure to keep a mapping from the "naughty" characters to their HTML entity equivalents, as well as a regular expression to find characters to convert. Once you've done the above, you can escape any string with:

```
  var escaped = "<b>Hello World</b>".encodeHTML();
```

The regular expression is written such that it avoids re-encoding existing HTML entities.

Comment: How could you escape apostrophes or double quotes using innerHTML, if it's possible at all?

Comment: @JimD you can't make the browsers do that; like I said, this is just their built-in behavior. I'll add an alternative function for doing HTML-escapes on a string.